# How to check multiple columns that don't equal another column?

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns "Option1" through "Option6". I would like to check if `value1` exists in any of the Option columns and does not equal to `value2` from the Result Column.

[image: Table Image]

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE (Option1 LIKE 'Apple' or Option2 LIKE 'Apple' or Option3 LIKE 'Apple' 
      or Option4 LIKE 'Apple' or Option 5 LIKE 'Apple' or Option6 LIKE 'Apple') 
      AND Result NOT LIKE 'Apple%'
```

I would like an outcome like this

[image: Result Table Image]

Comment: So what response you get? I see there is syntax error with `or Option 5 LIKE`. Also when using `LIKE` you usually want to add `%` in string, otherwise use `Option2 = 'Apple'`

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If your query is exactly as you show above then you have multiple typos. Also this would be much simpler if your table design was properly normalised eg, with columns *Option* and *OptionNo*

Comment: But the main question is probably: why do you have so many options columns?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)